# MySQL is not searching the element with (.) in it

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am selecting year_1 price with MySQL but the data 'co.in' year_1 price is not being selected.
my sql query is :

```
connection.query('SELECT tld,year_1 FROM domain_pricing WHERE tld = ? OR tld = ? OR tld = ? OR tld = ? OR tld = ? OR tld = ? OR tld = ? OR tld = ? OR tld = ?',[domainzone[0],domainzone[1],domainzone[2],domainzone[3],domainzone[4],domainzone[5],domainzone[6],domainzone[7],domainzone[8]],(error,rows,fields)=>{
    if(error){res.json({message:'Ooops something went wrong.',status:false,error:error})}else{
      console.log(rows)
    }
  })
```

optput is

```
    [RowDataPacket { tld: 'com', year_1: 10 },
  RowDataPacket { tld: 'in', year_1: 20 },
  RowDataPacket { tld: 'net', year_1: 30 },
  RowDataPacket { tld: 'org', year_1: 40 },
  RowDataPacket { tld: 'company', year_1: 60 },
  RowDataPacket { tld: 'community', year_1: 80 },
  RowDataPacket { tld: 'computer', year_1: 90 } ]
```

Comment: Try rechecking `domainzone[]` array, i think no problem in query

Comment: If you search for `tld = ? or ...`, you will get of course rows where that column is equal to one of your search parameters. `'in'` is `= 'in'` (and, assuming case-insensitive values, `'IN'` is also `= 'in'` ). But `'co.in'` is not `= 'in'`. Try e.g. [`like`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html).